# IntelliJ formats annotated method parameters in an unexpected way when they're not final

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I've setup the IntelliJ code style formatter to "chop down if long" for *Wrapping and Braces -> Method declaration parameters* and enabled the underlying "Align when multiline" option. (I've included a screenshot at the bottom)

If I now create a function like this:

```
public void foo(@Bar BarObj bar, @Foo final FooObj foo) {
    // do something
}
```

The by IntelliJ reformatted code looks like this (given my method declaration statement exceeds the hard wrap character limit):

```
public void foo(
    @Bar
        BarObj bar,
    @Foo
    final FooObj foo
) {
    // do something
}
```

But my expectation was that it would come out like this:

```
public void foo(
    @Bar
    BarObj bar,
    @Foo
    final FooObj foo
) {
    // do something
}
```

I'm really annoyed by this behavior since there doesn't seem to be any option in the code style settings to change this and it occurs unrelated to the number of annotation or the oder in which the final/unfinal parameters are put.
I also can't find anything regarding this online, even though I've spent a lot of time on Google searching for a solution or anybody who encounters the same problem.

My code style settings are:
[image: My code style settings]

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196021.